# Android media player with list view and service

Tags: java, android

I have implemented an Android media player that is clicking on songs text view will display the layout. The layout displayed with play pause .. and clicking on play stop works well.  Here I am thinking in users perspective to implement the below.

1. Clicking on songs text view should display the songs in list view and in the bottom of the layout small controls should display with play pause and stop
2. It should play even when other application is opened.

To achieve the point 2 I used media player service and for point 1, I used a `ListView' but not successfully implemented. Below is the code which play the song and and go till end.  From this point can anyone please help me to implement list view songs with service?

```
public class Songs extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public TextView songName, duration;
    private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
    private int forwardTime = 2000, backwardTime = 2000;
    private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private Context context;
    private int getCurrentPos=0;
    private int[] songs={R.raw.sample_song,R.raw.sleepaway};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context=getApplicationContext();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
        initializeViews();
    }

    public void initializeViews(){
        songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[getCurrentPos]);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songName.setText("Sample_Song.mp3");
        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
        seekbar.setClickable(false);
    }

    // play mp3 song
    public void play(View view) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
        durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
    }


    private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
            //              duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 12, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - 12));

            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    // pause mp3 song
    public void pause(View view) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    // go forward at forwardTime seconds
    public void forward(View view) {
        //check if we can go forward at forwardTime seconds before song endes
        if ((timeElapsed + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed + forwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }
    }

    // go backwards at backwardTime seconds
    public void rewind(View view) {
        //check if we can go back at backwardTime seconds after song starts
        if ((timeElapsed - backwardTime) > 0) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed - backwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }
    }

    // Go to next song
    public void next(View view) throws IOException{
        try {

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[getSongPosition()]);
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private int getSongPosition(){
        if(getCurrentPos==songs.length-1){
            getCurrentPos=0;
        }else if(getCurrentPos==0){
            getCurrentPos=getCurrentPos+1;
        }else{
            getCurrentPos=getCurrentPos+1;
        }
        return getCurrentPos;
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="songName" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mp3Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/music"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="songDuration" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_rew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="rewind"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="pause"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="play"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_ff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="forward"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```